# Determining # of calories using coffee-cup calorimter

Tags: thermodynamics

I created a coffee-cup calorimeter at home where I calculate the total amount of calories in a tortilla chip by burning the chip and measuring the temperature change of the water.

If the formula is Q = (m) (c) (ΔT)
where,
Q = s the energy in the form of heat captured by the water, expressed in calories, and
m = mass of the water expressed in grams, and
c = the specific heat capacity of water, and 
ΔT = change in temperature,

and my m=80grams, and temperature change was 20 degrees celsius, -does this mean the tortilla chip is 1.6 calories or do I have to multiply this value by 4.186 (which is the specific heat of water) to get a value of 6.69 calories?  Thank you.

Comment: It takes one calorie to raise 1 gram ( 1 milliliter) of water 1 degree C. So you had 1,600 calories. The !@#$%^ idiots doing food analysis decided that the "chemical calorie" was to small so they defined a "food calorie" as 1000 "chemical calories." // As a side note if you're burning something how do you transfer heat to the water? You'd need to account for the thermal mass of whatever apparatus was used to transfer the heat to the water.  You can get this by using an ice cube. Need to dry and weigh cube.